# Why was C not made a platform independent language?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, platform-independent

I recently read the dragon book of compiler design. It mentions that the compiler has intermediate code generation as one of its phases which produces a machine independent code. Then why was C not developed as a platform independent language like java?

Comment: Its designers were not looking for "a platform independent language like Java".  They wanted something close to the machine, higher level and more convenient than assembler, but still letting them write compact code that ran with comparable efficiency to assembler -- and using the compiler technology of the 1970s, and as a small, keep-it-simple project.

Comment: So the issue of platform dependence was ascertained  later in time?

Comment: "machine independent code" probably means "machine independent internal representation", but there will still be machine-dependent elements encoded in that representation. With that said, it's not clear what you're asking, exactly.

Comment: Portability has long been a goal of C, yes.  But it's achieved through very different means than Java.

Comment: I am interested to know why did the creators of C not embed the feature of plateform independence when it was possible (using intermediate code). Or is it not possible? if I am mistaken

Comment: It mostly is, unless you do stupid things with it.

Comment: @Curiosity101 because (a) performance and because (b) you still need a an appropriate interpreter or VM for your intermediate representation, for each platform that you want it to run on - what language will you write _that_ in?

Comment: Of course it is not possible. You have to pay a very high price (in terms of performance) for such a portability. Different computers have very different byte and word lengths, different pointer sizes, different alignment requirements, different endianness. You can simulate a behaviour of a lowest common denominator of a range of your target platforms, as Java did, but it is unavoidably slow. And when C was created, differences between hardware platforms were even more dramatic than they're now.

Comment: C was designed to allow the Unix kernel to be written in a higher level language than assembler.  Writing an o/s kernel in a high-level language was a reckless step at the time, back in the early 70s.  Things have changed dramatically since then!

Comment: @SteveSummit Are You THE Steve Summit , author of c-faq??

Comment: @SurajJain Could be. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit Sir , i have not read your book , but many of the time my curiosity have lead to me to an question , and often one of the source of its answers was your book  , i am planning to go through your book , once i knew enough `C` .Thanks FOr the amazing book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What the Dragon Book is describing is the following process:

1. Compile the source code into an intermediate machine-independent byte code format
2. Perform optimizations and analyses on that IR
3. Translate the IR to the target platform's actual machine code

The upside of this is that if you want to support additional systems, you just need to add a new code generator for step 3 without having to touch steps 1 and 2.

All common C compilers work this way. So if your question is "Why don't C compilers do what the Dragon Book describes?", the answer is: "They do".

Now you mentioned Java. What a Java compiler does is the following:

1. Compile the Java code into Java byte code. As far as the Java compiler is concerned, this is not an intermediate format, but the actual target language.
2. The end

Now to run this byte code you need a JVM, which interprets the byte code and/or JIT-compiles it. The optimizations and analyses usually happen during JIT-compilation. This is not the process described in the Dragon Book.

From the language implementers' point of view, this doesn't change the effort of supporting a new target system very much. You no longer have to change the compiler, but instead you have to change the JVM: Instead of having to add a new backend to the javac compiler, you instead add a new backend to the JIT-compiler. The effort remains basically the same.

The major difference is for the Java programmers: Instead of compiling the program for every target platform and distributing packages for each platform, you can now compile the code once and give the resulting package to everyone. Now the people running your code need to install an JVM to be able to use the package, so you basically moved the effort from the programmer to the end user, but installing a JVM is something you need to do only once (not for every Java program you want to run).

So instead of "write once, compile everywhere", you now have "compile once, run everywhere".

So why didn't C do the same thing that Java does? Performance. Interpreting byte code is slow (compared to running compiled code) and JIT-compilation leads to increased start-up time.

Comment: I think this is the answer, Looks to me like OP is confused about machine independent IR != platform independent language.

Comment: @ArturKink, not to mention that there is no such a thing (in context of C compilers) as machine-independent IR. Both GIMPLE and LLVM IR are heavily platform-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

C was initially designed for a particular use case, which involved a specific machine. Although it was loosely based on the language BCPL, which was implemented by way of a platform-independent virtual machine, the goal for C was to be able to write low-level code, such as an operating system, which meant that it needed to be able to take advantage of specific features of the target machine, particularly its ability to directly address individual bytes. By contrast, BCPL's underlying architecture is resolutely word-oriented.

The fact that Bell Labs was able to rapidly reimplement the Unix Operating System in their new language (C) certainly contributed ti its popularity. (At least, that's why I initially learned it.) To allow for a wider dissemination of the language, a version of the compiler was written more closely following the architecture outlined in the Dragon Book, with an initial generation of virtual machine code which is then used to produce code for a target machine. This Portable C Compiler was for many years a reference implementation, and continues to be available.

Other languages contemporary with C, notably Pascal, also used the tactic of targetting a platform independent vurtual machine, and it was once common to refer to virtual machine code as "P-Code" because that's what Niklaus Wirth's Pascal project called their target architecture.

Although GCC does not use a virtual machine as such, it does start by generating a liw-level machine-independent internal representation, simplifying the task of porting the compiler to new archutectures. And of course the Clang compiler produces LLVM (low-level virtual machine) code, which can be transpiled into various concrete machine codes, or interpreted directly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Because it was not feasible at that time.

The long answer: the Java platform is a language + virtual machine, Java code compiles to a something called ByteCode, then the virtual machine can take this byte code (it is similar to assembly language) and translates it to the relevant command at runtime, meaning the machine instruction that will be understood by the local machine.

Every architecture has it's own instruction set, meaning that an ARM architecture will not be able to understand code compiled for x86 architecture for example.

in C, the c code is compiled directly to machine instructions, these instructions are then performed by the local machine.
to get a behaviour like Java, you will need to have some kind of interpretor that reads C and translates it to machine code at runtime, this is no cheap task and was way too much for the computers of the time (c was invented in 1972) of course another way this could be implemented is to have the user compile your program before using it, which could be nice but probably will involve making your source code visible to the client, which is unwanted.
hopefully that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

C was originally designed and written as a "Write-Once, Compile-Anywhere" language, which was as close as they could get at the time to a Universal Language.

Processors and Architectures were so radically different, and resources were so small that the idea of a Universal Virtual Machine (like Java has) was just impossible.

The idea that a single code-base could be run through a compiler, and then you have the same software on any target platform was pretty incredible.

Comment: Doesn't the existence of P-Code (for example) contradict the incredibility of the concept in those supposedly naive days?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from leaving a number of things *implementation-defined* (in practice this is largely platform/ABI-defined, but strictly speaking doesn't have to be), C **is mostly a platform-independent language**. Indeed there are implementations of C (such as emscripten) that produce output in a form that can run on any machine platform with the right runtime environment for it. If software written in C makes assumptions about the implementation-defined (or worse, undefined) aspects of the language, then it might fail to work on some implementations/machines, but quite often the cause is more a matter of API/environment/library assumptions (like assuming POSIX, or Windows, or glibcisms) than making nonportable assumptions about the language itself.